# upload through $.post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to select my file trough a $.post command? at the moment i have it like

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {%>

<input type='file'></input>
<button>upload</button>

<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **impossible**.
You should use the iframe technique (search for this), which isn't ajax really but gives 'ajax sensation'.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Support gives some instructions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246